# Does Longtext slow down queries on other fields?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a website. Users in this website have profiles which has `Longtext` field. I'm in a dilemma. If I combine user and profile table, does it slow down my queries? I have intensive number of queries on user table. These queries are on `integer` numbers and do not relate to `Longtext` fields. The other way is to separate tables but they have 1:1 relationship which is nonsense here.

What to do?

Comment: I would suggest you ask this on DBA site. There is a high probability that you will get different answer then the accepted one. Mostly, it is about buffer pool and DB server cache which will contain those text columns even if you (queries) do not use them frequently ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns you're querying are indexed correctly, you should be fine.

Avoid `SELECT *`, and only retrieve the `longtext` column when you need it; if there's a lot of text in it and you don't use it you're wasting bandwidth.